# What's the difference between argmax and reduce_max functions in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I don't know what makes `argmax` and `reduce_max` apart. I am trying to learn TensorFlow and I use Python. I tried reading the documentation but couldn't really grasp what the difference is.

Answer (score 1):

`argmax` returns the **position** of the maximum value (typically the first one if degenerate).

`reduce_max`, same as `max` (which is a reducer e.g. an aggregating function) returns the max value itself.

Using numpy, instead of tensorflow, but the results are the same:

```py
arr = np.arange(5) + 1
# arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
print( np.argmax(arr), np.max(arr)) # (4, 5)
```

Comment: Adding links to documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/argmax https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_max